# Two <a> tags on the opposite side of the page, on the same line

Tags: html, css

I've been having trouble with this,I'd like to make a sort of "page navigation" with two links (to go forwards and backwards). On one line, I'd like a link on the far left side, and on the same line, a link on the far right. If the curly braces were the extent of the parent object, it would look something like this:

```
{Backwards                    Forwards}
```

The left side of the left link should be flush with the content boundary (is that what you'd call it? I mean just before padding sets in) and vice-versa.

Thanks.

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: Nothing that could affect this. It's enclosed in a div with some other content.

Comment: If you don't know how to do it how do you know it doesn't affect this?

Comment: Design wise, I wouldn't put navigation arrows on the far ends of the screen... the user would have to move mouse to extreme ends of the screen to go to next page. Kind of a hassle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a menu I was working on today actually. You just need to add `float: right;` to your second `<a>` tag. Here is my example:

[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/teputu/1/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 3):

So many ways to do it... one of them is using inline-block elements, the other one is using floats, etc.

Below are the two examples, the second one featuring a parent-child structure, like you wanted.

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  }

#l {
  float: left;
  }

#r {
  float: right;
  }
```

```html
<a>Backwards</a><div>Content</div><a>Forwards</a>
<br /><br />
<div><a id="l">Backwards</a> Content <a id="r">Forwards</a></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

float:left to the first one, float:right to the second one.
I do it normally with class names .fl / .fr and and a containing div with a clear:both.
Because of collapsing height of the div use a crossbrowser hack

```
<style>
/*---------------float / clear-------------*/
.fl {float: left;}
.fr {float: right;}
.clear:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.clear {display:inline-block;}
/* Hide from IE Mac \*/
.clear { display:block; }
/* End hide from IE Mac */
* html .clear {height:1px;}
/*---------------clear-------------*/
</style>

<div class="clear">
    <a class="fl" href="#">backward</a>
    <a class="fr" href="#">forward</a>
</div>
```